# What is the し particle and how do you use it?

Tags: grammar

I understand that obviously every Japanese textbook will go into this topic briefly... but I can never really come to grips with what it means in Japanese. If anyone could link me to a good Japanese dictionary entry about it that would be great (I can't find a good one that explains it)

I am interested in the し particle as used below...
歯は痛いし、歯医者には行きたくないし、困ったよ。

I was wondering if the し particle had anything to do with する/しか/しも.

職場は失うし、妻とは別れるし（で）、彼はひどく元気がない。
Here, it seems like し seems to turn the reasons into some sort of noun phrase because the author has stated you can use で with them.

Knowing the essential underlying meanings behind ので and から helps me to unconsciously decide between them... I kinda have no idea how to do the same with し so...
Can anyone enlighten me or link me to somewhere where I could be enlightened on the matter?

Comment: "Japanese as a foreign language" seems to teach a curious mixture of the overly formal and the slovenly informal.  This し is a prime example of the latter.  I would not teach it unless the student was already fairly fluent.

Comment: I agree! It is such a poorly taught language! I have been studying for sooo long and I have sooo much that I know but it is all just a mess in my head :(

I am desperately trying to sort it all out... but I have no idea which direction I should be heading!

Comment: Blame the JLPT test-setters. Don't know about the new exams, but 〜し was on the old 3級 syllabus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

し is used here to create a list, and I'd translate your example sentence as "My tooth hurts, I don't want to go to the dentist... it sucks." (lit: "I'm troubled")

It's *sort of*　like や in that it creates a list, but as I'm thinking about it, し is used more for a list of reasons that culminate in a conclusion stated later in the sentence.  I might describe my girlfriend as follows:
頭がいいし、かわいいし、日本語を勉強するし、お互いに話しやすいし、本当に好きだよ。

Here, I'm listing out various reasons I like her.  In your example, you're listing out reasons that you're troubled.  Hope that helps!

Comment: also, when you use し like this, it implies that this is a non-exhaustive list of reasons: you're just mentioning the most pertinent or important.