# What is the difference between し and て-form in connecting verbs together?

Tags: grammar, て-form, conjunctions, particle-し

Are there any differences between these sentences? Are they correct?

> 彼女は優しくて、綺麗で、楽しいんだ。だから大好きだ。
>   彼女は優しいし、綺麗だし、楽しいし。だから大好きだ。

How do し and て-form differ? How about these sentences:

> 今日はたくさん食べて、飲んだよ。
>   今日はたくさん食べたし、飲んだしよ。

Are these correct? Are they the same? Any help will be fully appreciated like always, especially quick and detailed answers!

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13397/what-is-the-%e3%81%97-particle-and-how-do-you-use-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

…し means that the clause with it is a part of reason for the main clause, in other words, 彼女は優しいし、綺麗だし、楽しいし。だから大好きだ implies that you might love him/her for other reasons than being kind, pretty and fun.

Incidentally, 飲んだしよ is not accepted in Standard Japanese, it sounds fairly rude (in its realm). よ is accepted in Standard Japanese only when it stands for a vocative case (dated expression) or a sentence ending particle. Other usages are considered a slang (including so called feminine language). Sentence ending particles need to follow either a terminal form of verbs (or adjectives) or another sentence ending particle. Since …し is  **basically** a conjunctive particle, the form of 飲んだしよ is not a main clause with a sentence ender but a sub clause with a filler (or interjectional particle or whatever).

Comment: So for the last clause by using し, should it be 飲んだし or 飲んだ? Should the last verb(or state of being) have し?

Comment: Are you asking if a clause that uses し should use し or not?

Comment: Yeah. Like 家で食べるし、飲むし、遊ぶし。 should the last verb(in this case 遊ぶ) have し?

Comment: Are you sure that 家で食べるし、飲むし、遊ぶし is not a complete sentence but technically a …し…し…から structure with the last …から omitted, in other word, that 遊ぶし is not the last verb?

Comment: It is a complete sentence than ends with 遊ぶ. So should I use the し or not? In this sentence I omitted the から.

Comment: If you want to finish the sentence with 遊ぶ and don't want to leave flavor of ellipsis, then you don't add し.

Comment: Wait, my last comment was wrong. If you save し from the last verb, it no longer functions as a reasoning clause but just a compound sentence (something similar to …たり…たりする。).

Comment: Wait does that mean I don't need to use から? So I can just say : 彼女は静かだし、綺麗だし、優しいし。大好きです。