# わからないし vs わからねいし

Tags: words, adjectives, anime, conjunctions, particle-し

I was watching some anime and realised that some character says わから**ね**いし instead of わから**な**いし. Is this just a slur kind situation where they change it so it's easier to pronounce, like how native speakers often say して**ん**の rather than して**る**の. (Also this is just my understanding might also be wrong)

One more thing, why do they add the **し** at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have heard a result of /ai/-to-/ee/ conversion described in the following questions (it's pronounced like ねえ (ねー), not ねい):

- [What does こまけー mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3746/5010)
- [What is じゃねぇか? What is its original form?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18454/5010)

し is a non-exhaustive reason marker. Depending on the context, it may work just like "you know" or sentence-final よ.

- [What is the し particle and how do you use it?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13397/5010)
- [Are there various ways to use ~し?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1361/5010)